# Can I make Visual Studio break on a user-defined C++ exception?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, exception, breakpoints

I have an application that throws many (handled) exceptions. There is one type of exception in particular that I would like to break on.

Is it possible to make the debugger break on a specific user-defined exception? I don't see why this wouldn't be possible, since it does know the type of the exception that was thrown.

I can work around this by setting a breakpoint in the exception's constructor, but it would be nice to know how to do it the 'correct' way.

Comment: http://www.gibmonks.com/c_sharp/csharpckbk2-CHP-7-SECT-15.html

Comment: Putting it in the constructor has always worked for me - if it works for you, why do you want another method? It also has the advantage of letting you explore the condition before the stack is unwound.

Comment: @MarkRansom Because you might not have the access to exception's source code in general case? BTW, letting VS stop will let you examine the call stack just as well (VS stops at exception throw, not catch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to the `Debug` menu and choose `Exceptions...` (or press `Ctrl+Alt+E`), you'll get a dialog:

[image: exceptions dialog]

You'll need to click the `Add...` button, enter your custom type name, and make sure that the checkbox by your new exception type is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Debug menu > Exceptions > Add`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use the [`__debugbreak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx) function