# Break into debugger when function is left via C++ exception?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, exception, visual-studio-debugging

Note: I know how to break when an exception is [thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10342383/321013).

However, I have the case where I would like to set a breakpoint inside a function so that when this function is left via an exception (as opposed to normal return) the debugger stops.

Would this be possible by maybe [setting a breakpoint in the disassembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5557y8b4.aspx#BKMK_Set_a_breakpoint_at_an_assembly_instruction_in_the_Disassembly_window)? If yes, how to find the correct instruction - if no, what else?

My code is x86, but I would be interested in a general answer that also covers x64.

<sub>I will note that both current answers address the issue via *adding code* which is not what this question is about. I would like to break on the function exit (unwinding) iff we exit via an exception *without* adding or changing any code.</sub>

Comment: Your debugger can probably break on exceptions. Would that meet your needs?

Comment: How about putting the break point in the exception objects constructor. If you derive from std::exception put a break point on std::exception::exception. That way you break before the actual exception is thrown but at the point where the error is occurring.

Comment: @Fred: See first line. I don't want to break on a specific exception - I want to break at a specific code point when any exception "passes through".

Comment: @Loki - Putting a breakpoint into exception ctor would be equivalent to break-at-throw site, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

In pure C++ you could always add a `try/catch` around the whole function body, and immediately rethrow the exception. Of course you'd put a breakpoint on the `throw` statement:

```
void foo() {
    try {
        // old function body
    }
    catch (...) {
        throw; // put a breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Comment: Would a release build optimise out? If so, this is cute.

Comment: @Bathsheba Theoretically it could be optimized out indeed. Now *will* the compiler do it, I have no clue. As usual, looking at the generated assembly is the best way to make sure.

Comment: It's a neat trick though if your debugger doesn't support trap on exception so +1.

Comment: Of course, this requires modifying the code and recompiling, which is not something I want to do when putting breakpoints. I consider this a very crude workaround.

Comment: @MartinBa Fact is, I've never seen a debugger that has the functionality you want. They can break when an exception is *thrown* but not when a function exits due to an exception being thrown. So the only solution to do what you want is indeed to use a workaround. I for one consider this to be much cleaner than setting a breakpoint in the disassembly (which you must inspect manually every time you make a modification to the code). YMMV.

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen that either - that's why I asked :-) -- As for "cleaner": When I have to modify code to debug something, I find that always a bad sign. I could just throw in a print statement for good measure and then I don't need the debugger at all. (Yeah, kinda exaggerating.)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class ExceptionDetector
{
     public:
          ExceptionDetector() {}
         ~ExceptionDetector()
          {
              if (std::uncaught_exception())
              {
                     std::cout << "Exception in Flight\n";  // Put break point here.
              }
          }
};
```

Now in your function (or method).

```
int myFunc()
{
     ExceptionDetector   exceptionDetector;

     // STUFF
}
```

If you put the break point int the destructor above.
You will pause the program just as it is about to exit the function when an exception is thrown.